# Meaning of quotient $E/E^{\#}$ in Relative cohomology $H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the following exerpt,

> **Chern Classes:**
> Throughout this section, we will use $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients and let $\xi=(E, X, \pi)$ denote a $d$ 'dimensional vector bundle with total space $E$, base space $X$ and projection $\pi$. We also use $E^{\#}$ to denote $E \backslash s_0(X)$, where $s_0: X \rightarrow E$ is the zero section.
> In the case where $\xi$ admits a $\mathbb{Z}$-orientation $\left\{\varepsilon_x\right\}_{x \in X}$, recall that there is a unique class $u_{\xi} \in H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right)$ (the Thom class) which restricts to $\varepsilon_x$ on each fibre. The Euler class $e(\xi) \in H^d(X)$ is then defined by the image of $u_{\xi}$ under the composition
> $$
> H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right) \longrightarrow H^d(E) \stackrel{s_0^*}{\sim} H^d(X) .
> $$
> This has the property that, if $\xi^{\prime}=\left(E^{\prime}, X^{\prime}, \pi^{\prime}\right)$ is another oriented $d$-dimensional real vector bundle and $(F, f): \xi \rightarrow \xi^{\prime}$ is an orientation-preserving bundle morphism, then $f^* e\left(\xi^{\prime}\right)=e(\xi)$. We say that $e$ satisfies the naturality condition.

here as you can see, the $E^\#$ is defined as $E \backslash s_0(X)$, and then the relative cohomology $H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right)$ is being considered.

I am unable to see the difference between, the zero section $s_0(X)$ itself and the quotient $E/E^{\#}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I mean, the how is the relative cohomology $H^d(E,E^\#)$ different from $H^d(s_0(X)$ itself. Or simply $E/E^\#$ is different from the $s_0(X)$ itself. In other words, how a $\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$ is different from $\mathbb Z-2\mathbb Z$

Comment: The Thom isomorphism says that $H^k(X)\to H^{k+d}(E,E^{\#}), x\mapsto \pi^\ast(x)\cup u_\xi$ (cup product) is an isomorphism. So in general the cohomology groups are different.